# Xamarin.KeyboardHelper : Don't open the keyboard at all without it opening and hiding

Tags: android, xamarin

In my Xamarin.Forms application I use KeyboardHelper to not show the keyboard on my Entry elements.
But on Android device, when I give focus to an element, my screen "jumps". The problem is that the keyboard opens and then closes immediately.

Demo [here](https://github.com/masonyc/Xamarin.KeyboardHelper/blob/master/Screenshots/androidDemo.gif)

Is it possible to make the keyboard not open at all?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to make the keyboard not open at all?

Yes. And you can create a custom renderer in your Android project:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Entry), typeof(MyEntryRenderer))]
namespace Forms.Droid
{
    public class MyEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer
    {
        public MyEntryRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

           if (Control != null)
            {
                // do whatever you want to the UITextField here!
                Control.InputType = Android.Text.InputTypes.Null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Wish it is a workaround for you.